# Applying different angles to segments of a linear-gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How can I apply different angles to the segments of a gradient, e.g. have the red and blue gradients at 45 degrees and green at 90 just like the image below?

[image]

```css
.gradient1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red 0%, blue 50%, green 50%);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gradient2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 0%, blue 50%, green 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient1"></div>
<div class="gradient2"></div>
```

Comment: So you want red and blue at 45deg and keep green at 90deg. right?

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite clear. Do you want one element (a div say) to have as its background the picture that you show at the top - red and blue diagonal on one half and all green on the other half? This can certainly be done with background-image linear gradients but I just wanted to check the outcome required.

Comment: yes, I need it as a background for a div. There should be clear vertical border to the green right half, but the red should transition gradually in to the blue at 45deg (which my image misses to show exactly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds a conic-gradient to me:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:conic-gradient(from -90deg at bottom,red,blue , green 90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:conic-gradient(from -90deg at bottom,red,blue 90deg, green 0);
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or maybe multiple layers with a linear-gradient

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue) left/50% 100% no-repeat
   green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```